# How can I get a question reopened?

Tags: support, specific-question

I asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/506643/how-many-cjk-fonts-do-i-need) and it quickly got closed for not being constructive (because people seemed to think I was asking for opinions, even if I wasn't.)

So I edited it to make it more clear what I was asking, but how do I get it reopened? I don't have the rep to vote to reopen.

This is important to me, because it's the only question I asked on this site so far. That means 100% of my questions are closed, and I don't know how close I am to a ban!
(If I'd asked more questions, getting one of them closed wouldn't be that much of a problem.)

Answer (score 2):

You can get it reopened by flagging it or posting about it on meta. As it currently stands, I see no reason to reopen.

Your question in inherently subjective. **Why** would *any* font be "better" than any other?

Unless you outline your criteria, you're not going to get proper answers. And **that** is why your question is closed.

If you just want to clear up space, remove them all. If you don't want to do that, explain why you don't want to do that.

Comment: I see I've got a communications problem then; I thought I was explaining why I did it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how the question can be answered objectively. Here's some of what you're asking for:

- which CJK font should I keep? Which is best?
- Completeness, usability, readability at smaller font sizes

These are inherently subjective. For example, what's readable for few folks at 10pt might be completely unacceptable for others

Comment: The immediate question is simply what one clicks on to get a question reopened.  There is no "click here to get a question reopened" in the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria for the "best" fonts (completeness, useability, readability) are subjects that are usually under debate, and without conclusive answers.

I mean, consider the question "What's the best font for websites?". You will find tons of pages on the internet discussing the question, and very few of these pages have similar answers:

[Google: Best internet font](https://www.google.com/search?q=best%20internet%20font)